# modifying CSS of a web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome plugin for speed read the articles on web. I want that the user can select the speed with which he wants to read the article and the plugin can highlight the text(each word) of the article with the same speed. This can be achieved by modifying the CSS via JavaScript of the webpage  but changes in CSS are only visible when the complete JavaScript is executed and all the changes are reflecting at once and not one word at a time.can I achieve it in a different way.below is my code.

background.js

```
/* Regex-pattern to check URLs against. 
   It matches URLs like: http[s]://[...]stackoverflow.com[...] */
var urlRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[^./?#]+\.)?getpocket\.com/;

/* A function creator for callbacks */
function doStuffWithDOM(element) {

    alert("I received the following DOM content:\n" + element.toString()); 
}

/* When the browser-action button is clicked... */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    /*...check the URL of the active tab against our pattern and... */
    if (urlRegex.test(tab.url)) {
        /* ...if it matches, send a message specifying a callback too */
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "report_back" },
                                doStuffWithDOM);
    }
});
```

content.js

```
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    // If the received message has the expected format...
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        // Call the specified callback, passing
        // the web-page's DOM content as argument
        //var outerHTML = document.querySelector('.text_body').outerHTML;
        //sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);
        //var outerHTML = document.all[0].outerHTML;
        var outerHTML = document.querySelector('.text_body').outerHTML;
        var outerHTML1 = outerHTML;
        var j=0;
        var k = 0;
        var searchText = ' ';
        for(i=outerHTML.indexOf(searchText);i<outerHTML.length;i = outerHTML.indexOf(searchText,i+1))
        {
            outerHTML1 = "<mark>" + outerHTML1.substring(0,i)+ "</mark>"+ outerHTML1.substring(i+1,outerHTML1.length-1);
            for(k=0;k<500;k++)
            {
                console.log(k);
            }
            k = 0;
            document.querySelector('.text_body').outerHTML = outerHTML1;
            //sendResponse(document.querySelector('.text_body').outerHTML);
            console.log(i);
        }


        sendResponse("it works!"); 
        /*for (index = outerHTML.indexof(" ") , index1 = 0; index < outerHTML.length() ; index1 = index ,index = outerHTML.indexof(index , " "))
        {
             outerHTML = outerHTML.substring(index1,index-1) + "<span class='highlight'>" + outerHTML.substring(index1,index+text.length) + "</span>" + outerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.outerHTML = outerHTML 
        }*/
    }

});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.getpocket.com/*"],
        "js":      ["content.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
    },

    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: So changing the css only when the section comes into view rather than entire page will be good enough for you?

Comment: yes that will be fine but CSS of the web content should be changed word by word .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/y6sur9h8/1/). I have left some functionalities like using a dynamic text to highlight, handling the text cases and the time interval. Hope you can work on these things. let me know if you need additional help.

Explaining the code used. I am finding all the text called `software` in my div and replacing it with `<span class='highlight'>software</span>` and later I have a interval function which runs every second (you must change this according to your user speed) and highlights the text word by word.

```
$(function(){ 
  var docText = $('#docContent')[0].innerHTML;
  var modifiedText = docText.replace(/software/g, "<span class='highlight'>software</span>");  
 $('#docContent').html(modifiedText);

  setInterval(function() {
  debugger;
     $('span.highlight:not(.highlight-active):eq(0)').addClass('highlight-active');
     }, 1000); //60*1000
});
```

My Div Section has

```
<div id="docContent">
      <p>
      software
    from wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
    for other uses, see software (disambiguation).
    computer software also called a program or simply software is any set of instructions that directs a computer to perform specific tasks or operations. computer software consists of computer programs, libraries and related non-executable data (such as online documentation or digital media). computer software is non-tangible, contrasted with computer hardware, which is the physical component of computers. computer hardware and software require each other and neither can be realistically used without the other.

    at the lowest level, executable code consists of machine language instructions specific to an individual processor—typically a central processing unit (cpu). a machine language consists of groups of binary values signifying processor instructions that change the state of the computer from its preceding state. for example, an instruction may change the value stored in a particular storage location in the computer—an effect that is not directly observable to the user. an instruction may also (indirectly) cause something to appear on a display of the computer system—a state change which should be visible to the user. the processor carries out the instructions in the order they are provided, unless it is instructed to "jump" to a different instruction, or interrupted.

    software written in a machine language is known as "machine code". however, in practice, software is usually written in high-level programming languages that are easier and more efficient for humans to use (closer to natural language) than machine language.[1] high-level languages are translated into machine language using a compiler or an interpreter or a combination of the two. software may also be written in a low-level assembly language, essentially, a vaguely mnemonic representation of a machine language using a natural language alphabet. assembly language is translated into machine language using an assembler.
      </p>
 </div>
```

And css used

```
.highlight-active{
  background-color:yellow;
  color:green;
}
```